# How to check existence of xml file in resources folder in java?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, classpath

I wanan check is the resources folder has a xml with the given name. I can do by using File class and then check exists() method, but I was wondering if I can refer to resource file as a Resource and not by File? I tried following but it does not seem to work :

```
 Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("resources/folder/test.xml");//this file is existing

 if(resource.exists())
    {
      System.out.println(" SUCCESS ");

    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println(" FAIL . RESOURCE NOT FOUND");
    }
```

Its always going else block  when this piece of code is executed.What did I miss?

Comment: Remove the `resources` part, that is actually the root of the classpath.

Comment: worked like charm.Thanks a lot.Add it as an answer if u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src/main/resources` is the root of the classpath (or the files in there are added to the root. So `resources/folder/test.xml` would expect a file in `src/main/resources/resources/folder/test.xml`. This is probably not what you want. Remove the `resources` part in the file path.

```java
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/folder/test.xml");
if(resource.exists()) {
  System.out.println(" SUCCESS ");
} else {
  System.out.println(" FAIL . RESOURCE NOT FOUND");
}
```

Should do the trick.